# Flutter: The top part of the application is not fully visible on the phone

Tags: flutter

Iam beginner in flutter,my device is Xiaomi and i am turn off the miui optimization
so, when i run app The top part of the application is not fully visible on the phone
How can I solve this issue?

The problem:

[image]

iam tried to turn off optimization and search on youtube and google to find solutions but failed

Comment: can you add some code for the implementation that you have done

Comment: Did you try using safe area ?

Comment: I think you are not using scafffold and body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter has a very helpful widget to solve problems like that, the **SafeArea** widget.

This widget is used to ensure that your content is displayed within the safe area of the screen. The **safe area** is the portion of the screen that is not covered by system UI elements like the status bar.

You can find more information and an explanatory video [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html).

A possible solution could be to wrap your content in this widget as suggested in the video mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is normally due missing foundational widget for building app screens such as `Scaffold()`

Basically your widget needs to be a direct if not an indirect descendant of `MaterialApp()` like so:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(//<===Not needed if it's already included in your launcher widget
      home: Scaffold(//<=== start with this as parent widget in any page
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My App'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Hello, World!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```